# Android: Set Ringtone for existing record in Mediastore.Audio.Media

Tags: android, ringtone

I am able to set the ringtone perfectly, when I insert the row in Mediastore.Audio.Media

```
 newUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);
```

But for an existing record i.e when am trying to insert the row again, logcat shows me database constraint error 19. So how do I work around this? Basically I need to set a .ogg file from my sound board app as a ringtone, which is already existing in the mediastore database... Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Delete the existing record in the database before inserting.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
```

**Hope this helps you too.**